# Vertex sliding along line until intersection

Tags: modeling

Is there a way to slide a vertex along a line until an intersection of another line, which has no vertex at said intersection like it is shown in the picture?

I am a total beginner in blender and couldn't figure this out by searching for tutorials,

[image: vertex slide until intersection]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit:**

Nowadays, by far the most convenient route to point-at-intersection is often to switch on 'Split Edges and Faces' in *Automerge*:

[image]

---

3 options to create a vertex at the intersection between two edges:

1. Activate and use The tinyCAD shipped add on > V2X: 'Vertex at Intersection'
2. <kbd>E</kbd>Extrude the edges to make faces, select them, and search for 'Intersect' (Spacebar in 2.79, F3 in 2.80). Check the 'Self Intersect' option. Delete excess vertices.

[image]

3. Create a plane below the edges, and Knife Project the edges down onto the plane, which will create a vertex at the intersection between the projected edges, (and possibly some surplus geometry) That vertex can become a snap target, or you can duplicate the edges out of the plane.

[image]

This last method can sometimes be quite useful ..  the lines only have to intersect in your chosen projection, which you define by the orientation of your plane, before  <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>Numpad 7</kbd> aligning your view to it, to execute the Knife Project.

Answer (score 1):

Use the snapping tool in edge mode and be sure it's activated. The magnet icon must be highlighted.

[image: The snapping tool]

Select the vertex and type twice on G (or shift+v as Ahmad said) to slide along the mesh until the second edge.

Comment: Be carreful in this case the second edge is not divided in 2 parts.

Answer (score -2):

Slide using Shift+V

Make sure snapping is on.. and set to vertex - closest .. and you will snap to the vertex on intersection.

Comment: You can't snap to geometry while vertex or edge sliding